# Android: how to load html string inside a WebView?

Tags: java, android, html, xml, webview

I have a webview in my layout file in android app and I want to load a video with html and javascript inside it. the html string that i want to use to load the video is:

```
video= '<div id="15518031408206776"><script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://www.aparat.com/embed/gJ8jm?data[rnddiv]=15518031408206776&data[responsive]=yes"></script></div>'
```

the WebView xml code is:

```
<WebView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        tools:ignore="WebViewLayout"
                        android:id="@+id/post_video" />
```

i also enable the javascriop in webview:

```
post_video.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)

post_video.loadDataWithBaseURL( null, video, "text/html", "UTF-8", null );
```

but the webview just show the plain text html code instead of video!

[you can see the result in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVBGC.jpg)

how can i solve this problem?

**Update:**

I solved the problem by using Html.fromHtml(video) to decode my html string! now it's working and the WebView shows the video.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding below attributes to webview

```
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Also add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to `application` tag in manifest file

Comment: Thanks for your Approach, but According to Android documentation: "Hardware acceleration is enabled by default if your Target API level is >=14..." and adding android:hardwareAccelerated="true" to application tag in manifest file did not solve my problem!

Comment: I solved the problem by using  Html.fromHtml(video) to decode my html string! now it's working and the WebView shows the video.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `loadData (String data, String mimeType, String encoding)` [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) instead, with the "text/html" mime type and "UTF-8" encoding.

Also, you should be wrapping your html content with `<html>` and `<body>` tags, so you will have a valid html document instead of just a valid document fragment.

Comment: I solved the problem by using  Html.fromHtml(video) to decode my html string! now it's working and the WebView shows the video. and Use of full html tags is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.
Make an adapter method like this.

```
  @JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("htmlString")
fun loadHTML(view: WebView, htmlString: String) {
    if(htmlString.isEmpty()){
        return
    }

    try{
        view.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
        view.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            }
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        }

        view.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8")
    }catch (ex: Exception){
        A35Log.e(TAG, "Error loading html string")
    }
}
```

Then use it in your xml code like this.

```
 <WebView
    android:id="@+id/wvHtml"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    bind:htmlString="@{viewModel.infoModel.hTML}"
    />
```

If you are not using data binding and you want to just use code, then simply take the code from the adapter example and load it directly into the webview. However, databinding and adapters are a very nice way to keep code clean and small.

Lastly, in pie it stopped allowing http traffic (clear traffic) to load by default. So if it fails to load for any reason, you may have to add to your application tag to allow non-secure html to load. I'm not sure if loading your own HTML string counts as "non-secure" or not, but it might.

```
 <application
    ...
   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

</application>
```